# Looking for a simpler way of writing this. Substring with insert and trim

Tags: c#, insert, substring, trim

```
((main.Substring(69, 7).Insert(((main.Substring(69, 7).Length - 2)),"."))).TrimStart('0')
```

It's a substring that adds a "." before that last 2 characters and removes any "0" in front of it.

I'm hoping to simplify that using 1 line only.  Is that as simple as it gets?  Any suggestion?  Thanks.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with at least 7 different sample inputs **and the expected results for each of those sample inputs**.

Comment: Well, for one thing, `main.Substring(69,7).Length - 2` can be reduced to `5` and then lots of excess parentheses can be lost.

Comment: Basically, im parsing a text file into a listview.  So a 004595 will look like 45.95 when displayed

Comment: Parse the number (leading zeroes are lost) and then divide by 100. Forcing yourself to continue dealing with strings is what's blocking your thought process.

Comment: @madreflection - that -2 is for the position of the "." with the INSERT

Comment: The second parameter is the length to extract. You then take `.Length` of that string. It's going to be 7.  `7 - 2 = 5`.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your trying to do but as @madreflection said, your line of code is exactly equal to `main.Substring(69, 7).Insert(5, ".").TrimStart('0');`.

Comment: @Ahmed - you're right! .. Thanks.. that worked.  Sorry, newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular expression in C# to solve this problem.

**OR**

As per my understanding (Based on your example code)
 1. Digit starts from 69th index and its length is 7 digit 
 2. You need to trim "0" from front of digit
 3. You need to put "." at last third place of digit

```
((main.Substring(69, 7).Insert(5,"."))).TrimStart('0')
```